# More Question Filtering options

Tags: feature-request, filtering

I realize that this may be a big request, but...

I think that instead of tabs on the recent question activity pages, or more likely as a new tab, adding a more advanced filtering option.

For instance, being allowed to exclude tags, filter by **accepted** answers or not, and, most importantly, being able to combine multiple filters!

E.g.: Filtering posts with tag `Javascript` without tags `Jquery` and `AngularJS` with no accepted answers and a score >= 0.

I feel like this is a biggish change that, if implemented as a new tab, wouldn't be that hard to implement, but would be very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter posts for all of these things through **search**.

- **Excluding tags:** Add `-` in front of the tag you want to exclude, eg `[discussion] -[filtering]` will find all [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) questions that don't have the [filtering](/questions/tagged/filtering) tag.
- **Accepted answer:** This can mean either searching for an answer that is accepted, or a question that has an accepted answer. Both are possible: use either `isaccepted:yes` or `hasaccepted:no`.
- **Score:** Simply search with the term `score:0..`
  (`score:0` will give you posts with a score of exactly 0, not greater than 0, as it would for other numbers.)
- **Multiple filters:** Add all of those search terms to [find what you're looking for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20-%5Bjquery%5D%20-%5BAngularJS%5D%20hasaccepted%3Ano%20score%3A0..).

**Tip:** these are all under the "Advanced search tips" next to the search button. For more info, see "[How do I search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching)"

Answer (score 1):

This is [already in beta testing on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate), and has been for years. In [6-8 months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) it will be released more widely.

Comment: Not really. This project has been frozen and its lead developer left Stack Exchange. They might still do it at some point, but I highly doubt it. More likely it will just be aborted, like other projects. (e.g. Teams)